# Reminders app tutorial, app does not load, issue with java file

Tags: android, classcastexception

I am learning Android Studio from a book called "Learn Android Studio: Build Android Apps Quickly and Effectively" By: Clifton Craig; Adam Gerber. I am following a tutorial on how to build a Reminders app and can't get the app to load. In the tutorial, I have been instructed to alter the onCreate() method with what is provided in the book, making sure to import what they provided.

The altered code is provided [here](http://www.screencast.com/t/FzrDvFtJqMJ).

The logcat is provided below:

```
01-18 06:04:55.460 2212-2212/com.apress.gerber.reminders I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-18 06:04:55.800 2212-2212/com.apress.gerber.reminders W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.apress.gerber.reminders-2/lib/x86_64
01-18 06:04:55.960 2212-2212/com.apress.gerber.reminders D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-18 06:04:55.960 2212-2212/com.apress.gerber.reminders E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.apress.gerber.reminders, PID: 2212
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.apress.gerber.reminders/com.apress.gerber.reminders.RemindersActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
       at com.apress.gerber.reminders.RemindersActivity.onCreate(RemindersActivity.java:22)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
01-18 06:05:00.980 2212-2212/com.apress.gerber.reminders I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2212 SIG: 9
```

The app will not load. The emulator gives an error. Any feedback on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `View` with the id `reminders_list_view` seems to be a `RelativeLayout` not a `ListView`.

Comment: You need to post your layout file as well

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView` says it all.

Comment: From the time that the book was published something in Android Studio changed. Remember that you now have content_reminders.xml file and an activity_reminders.xml file. You should try to add the id of reminders_list_view to the ListView widget (found in the content_reminders.xml file) what you were instructed to do in the beginning of the tutorial. Where you put that id is very important.